# Have some code in Wordpress show up when password is not entered and have other code show up when password is correct

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm going to try to explain this as best I can. I want to have a link appear on the page before the password is entered and have another link replace it when the correct password is entered and show the content of the page. So far, I have this code:

```
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) { ?>
<a href="http://link.com/">Link #1</a> // Link used when password not entered or wrong
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="http://link.com/">Link #2</a> // Link used when password entered correctly and shows content
<?php } ?>
```

Am I using the wrong conditional tag or is this not possible?

Comment: Seems like it should be possible.  It looks like post_password_required needs a post id as input like such: post_password_required( $post )

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: What is post_password_required( $post ) returning?

Comment: It's not returning anything

Comment: Are you sure that $post has a valid post id in it?

Comment: Do you mean like if ( post_password_required('173') ) ?

Comment: Not sure what I did, but... no problem!

Comment: You reminded me to put the valid post id.