# Have text appear in Wordpress footer and have different text appear in a password protected page

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to have a link in the Wordpress footer appear on a password protected page and have a different link on all other pages. So far, I have this code:

```
 <?php if ( post_password_required() { ?>
 <li><a href="http://link.com/">Link 1</a></li> //Link to appear on all other pages
 <? } else { ?>
 <li><a href="http://link.com/">Link 2</a></li>  //Link to appear on Password Protect page
 <? } ?>
```

But it's not working. Can anyone help me out? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Have some code in Wordpress show up when password is not entered and have other code show up when password is correct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722491/have-some-code-in-wordpress-show-up-when-password-is-not-entered-and-have-other)

Comment: Same solution as the other one!  Are you trying to pass the actual post id?  Like "178" or whatever?  You should find out the variable that the post id is stored in and pass the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you copy pasted the code from the template, but it seems you have an error. You forgot the close the `if` parenthesis **)** from

```
<?php if ( post_password_required() { ?>
```